# Emulate a list in C

Tags: c, list, set

Is there any way to emulate the list data structure in C? (What I really need is a doubly-linked list.)

More simply put, is there a good way to solve the Least Recently Used memory management technique?

My train of thought at the current time has me needing access to both the head and tail of the list (for obtaining/removing values and for inserting values, respectively).

Comment: Why would you _emulate_ a list when you can actually _implement_ a list? Also, how does this relate to LRU resource management mechanisms?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027484/lru-caches-in-c ?

Comment: I was asking because I didn't want to waste time implementing the C++ STL functions (lol) if there was an easier way. I would assume that this relates to LRU because this is the technique I would use. If there is a better way, please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An oft-cited list implementation in C comes from the Linux kernel: [list.h](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/include/linux/list.h)

It does a lot of things right, in the context of the C language.

Comment: @JojoJonas: Just remember that Linux kernel code is licensed as GPL version 2.